# trying to locate output file from postgresql \o -o command

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am making an automated script from terminal that creates a file with the output of `\l`

But I do not know where the `\o` command in postgresql prints out the file that it has made. The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html) doesn't inform where.

I did read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/how-do-i-find-postgresqls-data-directory), but no luck:

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

`\o` points at the named file in current working directory of psql.  As you found out, this has some issues in automated environments.

This means you have basically two options:

1. use absolute paths with `\o`
2. Alternatively you can use `\cd` to set your current working directory inside your psql script.

In your particular case, however, you know that `psql -l` gives you the same info?  That may be easier to manage in an automated environment.